# My C# code shows files but it has to show directories to

Tags: c#, file, recursion, directory

So, ive had a litle problem. I have a code for showing files in a directory but i need help with it. Right now it only shows the paths from files but it also has to show the directories of the files themselves. It is and has to stay a recursive code though but i don't think that will be a problem.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
System.Data.OleDb;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Geef de directory waar u de files uit zoekt: ");

        string directory = Console.ReadLine();

        string rootdir = @directory;




        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:/ALROapp/ConsoleApp/GetFilesAutomatiseerd.accdb");
        OleDbCommand cmdinsert = con.CreateCommand();
        con.Open();


        // Call EnumerateFiles in a foreach-loop.
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootdir, "*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);

            long size = fi.Length;
            DateTime creationTime = fi.CreationTime;

            // Hier toon je welke files je wegschrijft in de database
            Console.WriteLine(file);

            //Met deze sql code schrijf je de gegevens weg 1 per 1
            cmdinsert.CommandText = "Insert into tblBestand(fldBestand,fldCurrentSize,fldCreationData) Values('" + file + "','" + fi.Length + "','" + fi.CreationTime + "')";
            cmdinsert.Connection = con;
            cmdinsert.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }


        con.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();




    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Right now it only shows the paths from files but it also has to show the directories of the files themselves"? Do you want to get the full file path instead of the file name? If so, you can get that by `fi.FullName`. 

If you want to loop through both files and directories, you can do change `EnumerateFiles` to `EnumerateFileSystemEntries`

Comment: What i mean with that is that right now if i run my program it show f.e. 
c:\alro\robin\test1.txt but it has never shown c:\alro or c:\alro\robin and i need it to show that aswell and i will try your fix, thanks

Comment: "It is and has to stay a recursive code". Your code is not recursive.

Comment: i know not my whole code is recursive but i meanth the part that searches for files, it recalls the function when it is done in a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to get both directories and files. Building on sighol's suggestion to use `EnumerateFileSystemEntries`, you will also need to take the fact that directories don't have a `Length` into account.

The following code is working for me after a quick test in LINQPad, assuming you want the size of directories to be `0`:

```cs
foreach (var entry in Directory
    .EnumerateFileSystemEntries(rootdir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    var fi = new FileInfo(entry);
    
    var size = fi.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory) ? 0 : fi.Length;

    // ...
}
```

### Edit

If you want to get the combined size of all files in each directory, you can change the `size` calculation line to the below. I would use caution though, because it could potentially be a huge performance hit. There are probably better ways of doing this.

```cs
var size = fi.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory)
    ? Directory.EnumerateFiles(fi.FullName, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Sum(path => new FileInfo(path).Length)
    : fi.Length;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, it helped me a huge amount already but is it possible for the directories to be the size of everything inside?